# if statement on onCreateView for first view

Tags: java, android

Im trying to create an if statement on `onViewCreated`

```
@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);


    date = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textDate);
    date.setText(DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance().format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime()));
}
```

whereby if the view is first time, set this two line:

```
date = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textDate);
        date.setText(DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance().format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime()));
```

Are there any other methods i might not have thought of and missed or the if statement is of the more viable ones here.

Here's the rest of the code:

```
public class Notifications extends Fragment {
TextView servingqueue;
TextView date;


DatabaseReference mRootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference mServingQueue = mRootRef.child("ServingQueue");


public Notifications() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);



    mServingQueue.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            Double number = dataSnapshot.getValue(Double.class);
            servingqueue.setText(String.valueOf(number));

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);

}

@Override
public void onDetach() {
    super.onDetach();

}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_notifications, container, false);
    // Inflate the layout for this fragmentid.queueServing);
    servingqueue = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.queueServing);
    return rootView;
}
@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);


    date = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textDate);
    date.setText(DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance().format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime()));
}

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only want to set it the *first* time, then you can check if `savedInstanceState` is null.  If it's null, then the entire `Fragment` is brand-spanking new.  If it's not null, then you're coming back from a screen rotation or something.

However, your TextView will suddenly be empty because it'll be created, so here's another option.

In `onSaveInstanceState`, save the state of the `TextView`,

```
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle b) {
   super.onSaveInstanceState(b);
   b.putString("DATE_TEXT", date.getText().toString());
}
```

Then, in your `onViewCreated()`, retrieve the text like so:

```
@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

   String dateText = (savedInstanceState != null) ? 
          savedInstanceState.getString("DATE_TEXT") :
          DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance().format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());

   date = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textDate);
   date.setText(DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance().format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime()));
}
```

Comment: It triggers the savedinstance correctly. But the point of why i made the if statement in the first place was because the time&date created by those 2 lines updates to the latest time the moment i switched back and forth to this fragment. Your method still triggers the time&date after i switch back to this fragment. Is there a method where the time&date stays static after the first view?

Comment: @AnonymousVagrant: No.  You have to save it somewhere.